# Does android canvas draw on a bitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am working with the canvas of a SurfaceView and don't quite understand how canvas handles its draw calls.
What I think so far: Canvas is backed by a Bitmap so things I draw are directly saved as pixel values in that Bitmap.

What I then don't get is this: Canvas allows operations like scale, translation and "out of screen" drawing but all those things would require a dynamically sizeable Bitmap (because I can for example translate to wherever I want) so how is this possible?
Also I noticed when scaling drawn things like lines and circles up, they do not get pixelated at all which is strange if they where written on a bitmap first and then scaled up considerably.

Right now I implemented scaling and translation by modifying the variables in the draw calls directly. Is it more performant/best practise to skip this and use canvas' scale and translate functions instead?

What would that mean for the image quality of non Bitmap shapes when I scale them up considerably?

Can I savely draw at coordinates way "out of screen" and translate them back without any problems?

Comment: You can have a look at [Advanced Android in Kotlin 02.2:
Drawing on Canvas Objects.](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-canvas#0)

Answer (score 0):

You scale shapes as well using `Matrix()` e.g.

```
private fun scalePath(path: Path, scale: Float) {
    val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
    val rectF = RectF()
    path.computeBounds(, true)
    scaleMatrix.setScale(scale, scale, rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY())
    path.transform(scaleMatrix)
}
```

Scale you path by giving any scalling point, maybe `1.25f` and the shape will transform itself.

Answer (score 0):

Does android Canvas draw on a bitmap?

The answer is yes and no.

It depends, it can be backed by a bitmap or it can be hardware rendered which might not use a bitmap and it can also use a PDF document as used by Android's PdfDocument class.

Android canvas uses the [Skia](https://skia.org/) graphics library to do it's drawing.

For "What would that mean for the image quality of non Bitmap shapes when I scale them up considerably?"

From memory if your Paint has anti alias on, then the quality is quite ok.

For "Can I safely draw at coordinates way "out of screen" and translate them back without any problems?"

Yes up to a limit, as there are limits on the size especially if using a bitmap backed canvas because bitmaps are memory hungry and the VM has a limited amount of memory it can use.

Obviously if using scale and translate with user input then you might need to handle adjusting user input coordinates.

Comment: Assuming canvas uses a Bitmap how is the dynamic size aspect handled than? I mean this Bitmap would need to be virtually infinite so you can draw anywhere. Also when I draw objects lets say only for 10000<x<15000 (out of screen) would his create a Bitmap of size 15000 or 5000 in x direction?

Comment: I don't know how Skia handles the bitmaps, I think the default max size of the bitmap is 32Mb and using 4 bytes per pixel.